# C++ 20 coroutines on AVR

Tags: c++, c++20, avr, avr-gcc

Is it possible to use C++20 coroutines on AVR µC? I'm currently working on a hobby embedded project and being able to use proper coroutines would be really nice. I'm aware that they come with dynamic memory requirements, but I'm not that constraint that that'd be a problem.

In the worst case, I can implement everything myself, except for `std::coroutine_handle`. I think this one requires compiler support (at least after a quick scan of MSVC's implementation).

So is there a working version of `std::coroutine_handle` available for AVR targets (and anything else that requires special compiler support)?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl not really unfortunately. I know what a coroutine is and how it works, the problem is I don't know if there's compiler support for it in avr-gcc.

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood you, like you want to avoid malloc at all costs, but you said it is ok. :)

Comment: Did you find any solution for that? I just tweakes <coroutine> a little bit and then it compiles. But then I get some undefined symbols ...

Comment: @wimalopaan nope. I don't think you can get this by just tweaking some headers. This probably requires some compiler intrinsic.

Comment: Well, I get three undefined symbols: for the new/delete-operator functions (that's obvious) and for a function return 'Frame*' - whatever that means... My intend was to use some sort of custom-allocator instead of heap-allocation.

Comment: @wimalopaan Unfortunately I don't really have the time for larger experiments right now, but if you make any progress on this please keep me updated. What I have seen from MSVC's side is that compiler support is required, see [this](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/coroutine#L77) for example.

Answer (score 1):

In theory it should "just work".  At least in the gcc compiler?  The C++ standard says coroutines are allocated dynamically on the heap (ie it calls new on each task<>) so you have to be carful about the memory use of each task<>.

Hell even a paper was published here about it that looks very promising.
[C20 Coroutines on Microcontrollers - What we Learned](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/339221041_C20_Coroutines_on_Microcontrollers_-What_We_Learned)

This isn't like exceptions where you have to go though a bunch of rewind tables, each task<> is allocated in its own little box.

In "theory" the compiler should allocate the task within the caller if its life is just IN the caller, but just in case you should override the "struct Coroutine::promise_type" new operator to debug that.  Not sure if GCC put that in or not as I could not find the appropriate pull.